# Я могу потерять возможность задавать вопросы

Tags: обсуждение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за того что на мои вопросы в последнее время ставят минусы, я могу потерять возможность их задавать. Я не считаю что мои вопросы плохие, чтобы так их оценивать.

P.S. Представите, если кто-то специально отслеживает и плохо оценивает мои вопросы. Мне кажется за этим должны следить модераторы.

Comment: Типа дважды задавать и удалять один и тот же вопрос нормально?

Comment: Если вы внимательно прочтете все правила (в "справке и прочих ресурсах"), то легко сделаете вывод, что откровенно отвечать не ваш вопрос запрещается

Comment: Если кто-то целенаправленно ставит вам просто так минусы, система это автоматически отследит и откатит.

Comment: _«Я не считаю что мои вопросы плохие, чтобы так их оценивать.»_ - этот фактор не имеет определяющего значения: **решение о качестве вопроса принимает сообщество**. То есть, если сообщество считает вопрос некачественным, значит вопрос некачественный, точка. И вместо попыток противоречия/противостояния этому общественному мнению и принятым здесь нормам, **лучше привести вопрос в порядок**, в соответствие этим нормам (разве этому действию что-то мешает?). Ну и конечно же, если тебя не устраивают гласные и негласные нормы сообщества, имеешь полное право его покинуть (в свое время, я так поступил).

Comment: Здесь минусы потому, что непонятно, чего вы от нас хотите. Я бы еще понял, если бы вы показали заминусованный вопрос, и попросили объяснить, как его улучшить. *"специально отслеживает и плохо оценивает мои вопросы"* Три раза "ха".

Comment: Когда вопрос хороший, качественный и интересный, его не минусуют, а отвечают на него. Однако, получая вместо ответов минусы, это повод задуматься "почему". Успехов!

Answer (score 6):

Да, вы можете потерять возможность задавать вопросы. Обратите внимание на то, как вы их задаете, соответствуют ли они требованиям сайта. Даже в текущем вопросе нет конкретности и пользователи отмечают его тревогами.